# Split PDF into 10 page sets (python)

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I need to split a roughly 380 page pdf file into sets of 10 pages using python. My initial thoughts are to use PyPDF2 but I have no experience with it. I do need a mechanism to ensure the final PDF is saved despite it being under 10 pages. (eg. 383 page pdf should save as 38 10-page PDF and a 3 page pdf).

Comment: Have you tried reading the PyPDF2 docs to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post your current code? See also [ask].

Comment: I was able to use PyPDF2 after looking at the docs, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Use pyPDF2 to read the PDF file. Use `PdfFileReader.getNumPages()` to get the page count. Split the pages into groups of ten, adding each to a `PdfFileWriter` instance. Repeat for any leftover pages.

The `basic_features.py` sample code in the pyPDF2 repo makes this pretty clear.